# Defining the propagator using the positive and negative frequency of the field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator, propagator

I am currently reading some notes on QFT and in the notes it defined that
$$
\phi(x)=\phi^+(x)+\phi^-(x)
$$
where
$$
\phi^+(x)=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32E}a_ke^{-ikx}
$$
and
$$
\phi^-(x)=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32E}a\dagger_k e^{ikx}.
$$
Now, it the says that
$$
D(x-y)=\langle0|\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle=\langle0|\phi^+(x)\phi^-(y)|0\rangle= \langle0|[\phi^+(x),\phi^-(y)]|0\rangle=[\phi^+(x),\phi^-(y)].
$$
First, going from the first one to the second one I got:
$$
\langle0|\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle=\langle0|\phi^+(x)\phi^+(y)+\phi^+(x)\phi^-(y)+\phi^-(x)\phi^+(y)+\phi^-(x)\phi^-(y)|0\rangle
$$
The ones with the $\phi^+$ acting on $|0\rangle$ will be zero (right?), so this ends up with
$$
\langle0|\phi^+(x)\phi^-(y)+\phi^-(x)\phi^-(y)|0\rangle
$$
which isn't the same. What did I do wrong?
Another question is that for the last one, where did the $\langle0|$ and $|0\rangle$ in between the commutator go?

Comment: $\langle 0|\phi^-(x)\phi^-(y)=0$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, How? it has the creation operator

Comment: @Gradient137 the creation operator acting on the vacuum bra is zero since it is the conjugate of the annihilation operator acting on the vacuum ket.

Comment: omg I'm stupid.

Comment: Oh but where did the bra and ket go though for the last one?

Comment: You can show that that commutator is no longer an  operator  but just a complex function of $x$ and $y$, so its expectation value is equal to itself.

Comment: @Gradient137, It's okay mate, we learn through mistakes and iterations.